# Youtube API keyword search for latest videos added this week

Tags: android, api, youtube-api, keyword-search

coding an Android app, what should be added to the search url, so that the results listed are latest video songs that are added this week `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=latest%20video%20songs&max-results=50"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`&filters=week&lclk=week`

Comment: I tried adding here, the search results only latest video songs no filtered results "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=latest%20video%20songs&filters=week&lclk=week&max-results=50"